# Read TCP packets directly as hex

Tags: vb.net, tcp, hex, packets

I have this `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient`. I can make a connection and write packets to it accurately. The problem is want to read the packets as it is (as caught by sniffers in the hex form like 0F 03 56 56 etc.)

I tried looking at examples of `GetStream.write` but I fail to read them in such way. I also tried using a streamreader then convert the packets to hex but the thing I connect to sends screwed up packets which can't be converted or simple not in string form.

I hope I'm clear enough.

```
Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte 
' Read can return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead. 
' This method blocks until at least one byte is read. 
netStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize)) 
' Returns the data received from the host to the console. 
Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
```

Comment: What happens when you do read?  Line catches on fire?  Show some code.

Comment: Edit your post.  Don't put code in a comment.

Comment: I got some working code from another forum Thanks for your patience !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! Here it is:

```
Dim Bytes() as Byte = New Byte(1024){}
Array.Resize(Bytes, TcpClient.Client.Receive(Bytes, SocketFlags.None))

For Each B As Byte In Bytes
    Debug.Print("Byte in HEX Format: " & B.ToString("X2"))
Next
```